# Given $abc=1$ and $0< c \leq b \leq1\leq a$, prove that $8(a+b+c)^2\le9(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)$

Tags: inequality, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

I can't make progress with proving this inequality.

I have tried opening the brackets and using $abc=1$ in order to obtain the following:

$$a^2+b^2+ \frac 1{a^2b^2}+18+9a^2b^2+\frac 9{a^2}+\frac9{b^2}\ge 16 \left (ab+\frac 1a+\frac 1b \right)$$

Comment: If possible please solve using standard algebraic inequalities only and not tecniques like differential calculus

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We begin by observing that if $a=b=c=1$, then the two expressions are equal to each other.

Expand everything. Use the equation $abc=1$ to get rid of compound terms. Gather terms with each variable separately. Use the preceding observation to factor each nominator.

$$\begin{align} & 9(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)-8(a+b+c)^2 \\ &=9\bigl(1+a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2b^2c^2\bigr)-8\bigl(a^2+b^2+b^2+2ab+2bc+2ca\bigr) \\ &= 9\Bigl(1+a^2+b^2+c^2+{1\over c^2}+{1\over a^2}+{1\over b^2}+1\Bigr)-8\Bigl(a^2+b^2+c^2-{2\over c}-{2\over a}-{2\over b}\Bigr) \\ & ={a^4+6a^2-16a+9 \over a^2}+{b^4+6b^2-16b+9 \over b^2}+{c^4+6c^2-16c+9 \over c^2} \\ & ={(a-1)^2(a^2+2a+9) \over a^2}+{(b-1)^2(b^2+2b+9) \over b^2}+{(c-1)^2(c^2+2c+9) \over c^2}\end{align}$$
It is now obvious that this last expression is always $\geq 0$, and that it is $=0$ only in the case when $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: Thank you Per Manne. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Since the right side of your inequality does not depend on substitution $a\rightarrow-a$,

it's enough to prove it for positive variables.

We'll prove that your inequality is true for all positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $abc=1$.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, our inequality is equivalent to 
$$8\cdot9u^2w^2\leq18w^4+9(9u^2-6v^2)w^2+9(9v^4-6uw^3)$$ or

$f(v^2)\geq0$, where
$$f(v^2)=9v^4-6v^2w^2-6uw^3+u^2w^2+2w^4$$
Since $f'(v^2)=18v^2-6w^2>0$, it remains to prove our inequality for a minimal value of $v^2$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$ and $c=\frac{1}{a^2}$.

We obtain $(a-1)^2(9a^6+18a^5+13a^4+8a^3+21a^2+2a+1)\geq0$.

Done!

Comment: Calculus is unnecessary here to find $\min f$. For $A>0$ the least value of $AX^2+BX+C$ is $D=(4AC-B^2)/4A$ because  $AX^2+BX+C=D+A(X-B/2A)^2.$ But it's a logical answer.

Comment: @user254665 I meant that $f$ is an increasing function and from here $f$ gets a minimal value for equality case of two variables from $\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I don't understand how $f'(v^2)-18v^2-6w^2>0$. Can you please detail further. Also, is there a way to do this without differential calculus? I am looking for something that is Grade 10 algebra level (maybe it is not possible to do this with Grade 10 math - but it appeared in a Grade 10 level Junior Olympiad set).

Comment: In other words is there a way to do it without the $uvw$ method?

Comment: @Nirvanacat It's typo. It must be $f'(v^2)=18v^2-6w^2>0$.

Comment: @Michael - can you explain how the remaining terms in $f'(v^2)$ go to zero i.e. $-6uw^3+u^2w^2+2w^4$? I can see that for $w=1, dw/dv=0$ but why is $du/dv=0$? Don't we need to show that $u$ and $v$ are independent variables? Finally, why is $18v^2-6w^2$>0? Sorry if these are obvious questions - I am not very familiar with the $uvw$ method.

Comment: @Nirvanacat $w^3$ and $u$ don't depend on $v^2$. Hence, $\frac{d(w^3)}{d(v^2)}=\frac{du}{d(v^2)}=0$. Also we have $v\geq w$.